# Mojo resolving controller and action syntax to subref?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Given a syntax like

```
$c->routes->get($path)->to("$controller#$sub");
```

I would like to know which sub `$controller#$sub` resolves to on dispatch. Is there a simple method to get the ref of the sub? You can hard-set `->namespaces()` so I assume it's not always as simple as `$controller::$sub` because you could have `namespace::$controller::$sub`.

Comment: Seems like the logic for selection of the class of the sub is defined in [`_class()`](https://metacpan.org/release/Mojolicious/source/lib/Mojolicious/Routes.pm#L107)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to do this using the api, but there is a private method [`_class()`](https://metacpan.org/release/Mojolicious/source/lib/Mojolicious/Routes.pm#L107) that will give the controller object that contains the sub. Here is an example:

**./lib/MyApp/Controller/Foo.pm**:

```
package MyApp::Controller::Foo;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';
sub welcome {
     my $self = shift; 
     $self->render(text => 'Hello there.');
}    
1;
```

**./myapp.pl**:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use lib './lib';

get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->render(text => 'Hello World!');
};
my $namespaces = app->routes->namespaces;
push @$namespaces, 'MyApp::Controller';
app->routes->get('/welcome')->to('foo#welcome');
app->hook(
    before_dispatch => sub {
        my $c = shift;
        my $field = { action => "welcome", controller => "foo" };
        my $obj = $c->app->routes->_class( $c, $field );
        my $method = $field->{action};
        my $subref = sub { $obj->$method( @_ ) };
    }
);
app->start;
```